# Debian Guest reset network adapter after snapshot restore ignores config on VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, debian

I am using a virtualbox 5.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 as a host and a Debian 9 as a guest.

I have configured my Debian guest system to have a static IP (192.168.56.101) with a host-only adapter (192.168.56.1/24) no dhcp.

This configuration is written into `/etc/network/interfaces.d/setup` on the guest and works perfectly when the machine is booted up regulary. The host can ping the guest and the guest can ping the host.

However, if I take a snapshot and later on restore that snapshot the adapter is reset and the configuration ignored. The host cannot ping the machine and the machine cannot ping the host. A `/etc/init.d/network restart` fixes the problem. Consequently it cannot be the adapter or the host but must be an issue on the guest.

The reset itself is not the main issue, but the blatant disregard of the configuration is the problem after the reset. I am fine to wait a few seconds but I cannot log into the machine by hand as the machine is run headless in production.

**How can I force the adherence to the network configuration file after an adapter reset?**

The only related `dmesg` entry on the guest are:

```
[...] pcnet32 0000:00:03.0 enp0s3: link down
[...] pcnet32 0000:00:03.0 enp0s3: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex
```

While trying to find a dirty cronjob hack I encountered this entry in `/var/logs/cron.log`:

```
..... debian systemd-timesyncd[297]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to have a cron job each minute. The cron job checks whether the network adapter has an IPv4 address. If not `/etc/init.d/network restart` is run.

A really ugly hack but it fixes the issue at hand.